# Redirected to j_spring_security_check via GET method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a strange re-occurring problem with requests being made to j_spring_security_check via GET method.
All my login forms use POST to j_spring_security check for posting login credentials. Yet, application users reported on several occasions that sometimes they get an error page when trying to log in. I tracked those situations in the logs and it looks like people visit the login page and then next request is GET to j_spring_security_check.

It happend to me once too, but I cannot reproduce it.

Do you have any ideas why this may happen? Could spring security redirect to j_spring_security for some reason?
I double checked html and javascript there are no mentions of j_spring_security_check except in the action field of form elements which all have method set as POST.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: additional information:
WebApp is served by Tomcat. There is Apache reverse proxy in front of it. Pages that contain login forms pass w3c validations.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am having the same issue. From some reason the reqeust is redirected via GET. It doesn't even reach my custom authentication filter. The second request does, however, as it is GET there is no password and it fails.

Comment: @FilipMajernik Not really resolved yet :( We have currently written it off to a browser bug because it seems to mostly happen to Chrome on Mac. Take a look at this url: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-bugs/iDqpiApiBcc/sqzihoh61e4J We implemented suggestions from there (e.g. add enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to forms) Unfortunately, logs show that it also rarely happens in other browsers (which I hope are actually bots and not real users/browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost a month, we have finally figured out why this thing happens in google Chrome.
Apparently, if you submit a form using SHIFT+ENTER Chrome will open a new window and make a GET request instead of a POST request. Since some users have uppercase characters / special characters as a last letter of the password they type in the last letter with shift pressed and the press enter to log in while not yet releasing shift key. And the result is GET request to j_spring_security check. We will fix this by intercepting shift + enter in javascript.